# writing specific rows from one csv file to another csv file in python

Tags: python

Suppose , I have an input.csv file which has 10 rows.Now i have to write only the odd rows to another csv file output.csv.how to do this using csv in python?
I tried using writer.writerow but ,it writes only the last odd row.That is , it overwirtes the rows from input.csv in just one row in output.csv.
how to resolve this?

```
def filter_rows(s):
 r=0
 data=[]
 with open('csv/github_issues_preproc1.csv',  'rb') as                                         f,open('csv/preproc1f.csv',  'wb') as f_out:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  writer = csv.writer(f_out)
  for row in reader:
   r=r+1
   if r==s:
    data.append(row)    

  writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: if s is a list of row indices then your check should be `if r in s:`. if you only need to check for evenness, you don't need s `if r%2 == 0` (even) `if r%2 == 1` (odd).

Comment: How did you open `f_out`? You have to use `f_out = open(filename, 'a')` instead of `f_out = open(filename, 'w')`. `a` appends to a file while `w` overwrites it. Futhermore, you're code example is wrongly intended and incomplete.

Comment: yes. using 'a' while opening the file worked. Thank you.